# How to add table in between two \item commands

Tags: tables, positioning, itemize, grouping, center

I insert a table command between two itemized items, but the table appears at the top of the page. please help me locate this at the right place it means to be. thank you.

Ardalan

Comment: if the table is part of the list just use `tabular`. You have probably surrounded it by `table` but the only purpose of that environment is to take its content out of the document flow and allow it to be re-inserted elsewhere to help with page breaking.

Comment: Thank you very much David Carlisle, I changed it to tabular and error resolved. can I use caption for tabular either? it shows errors for that line: \caption{*}

Comment: using \begin{table}[h!], I was able to solve this problem, but what does [h!] mean?

Comment: `[ht!]` is the wrong answer although it may work in some cases. It means the table is removed from the document flow but may be added where it is in the source (`h`) or top of a later page (`t` latex may warn that it is adding this) the `!` means to ignore the constraints set to enforce good typesetting.

Comment: Thank you so much David, I learn so much from you. how can I solve this then? I can't make caption to tabular only.

Comment: arguably the reason for having a caption is _because_ the table floats and you should reference it by "as seen in table \ref{zzz}" rather than assuming the table is immediately following teh text, but other wise you can use captionof or the [H] otption see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8625/force-figure-placement-in-text